# Pad Array of Doubles with Previous Values

Tags: list, scala

I have a simple problem which I am failing, so seeking help here.

I have an Array[Ints] something like:

```
val A = Array(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,4,5,0,6,6)
```

I want to make it such that if the Int in A is a zero, it should inherit the previous non-zero number, Desired output should look like:

```
Array(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
```

so I tried to zip them:

```
(A.drop(1),A.dropRight(1)).zipped.map((x,y)=>(x._1,y._2 match{
case 0 => x._2
case _ => y._2}))
```

However, this is not working as it only produce a vector of

```
[1,1,0,0,2,2,0,3,4,5,5,6,6]
```

Any efficient way of executing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
scala> val A = Array(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,4,5,0,6,6)
scala> A.scan(0) {case (i, j) => if (j != 0) j else i}.tail
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try scan method:

```
A.scan(0) { case (a, b) => if (b != 0) b else a}.tail
```